# Postgres как создать таблицу?

Tags: postgresql

нужно создать таблицу в нужной мне бд.

то есть есть несколько баз данных:

бд1

бд2

бд3

и мне необходимо сделать запрос на создание таблицы допустим в бд2

запрос делается из программы, поэтому как выбрать базу данных для создания таблицы? 
спасибо.

Comment: Установить соединение с именно нужной БД.

Comment: установлено, запрос отправляется, но таблица не появляется в требуемой бд

Comment: а где появляется либо с какой ошибкой возвращается?

Comment: Или запрос выполняется без ошибки, или не выполняется с ошибкой. Какой вариант в данном случае? Если без ошибки - выполнен ли после создания таблицы коммит?

Comment: никакик ошибок не приходило, просто коммитилось и все.
причина была в том, что программа не хотела подключаться в нужной базе данных, потерял statement в методе.
в общем все заработало, спасибо